# Probability and Normal Distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, sample

(sampling distribution) We randomly draw another sample of size $10$. What is the probability that the mean word count of these $10$ songs is greater than $436.531 = 374.9149 + \dfrac{2∗97.42498}{\sqrt{10}}$?

The mean is $374.9149$.
The standard deviation is $97.42498$.
The sample size is $10$. The answer is $0.002$. How? I know we have to go above $436.5319$ and calculate the probability. The normal distribution is $68\%-95\%-99.7\%$ cutoffs.

Comment: A couple of hints: (1) The normal distribution isn't just 68%-95%-99.7% cutoffs.  (2) The normal distribution is only appropriate with such small samples if you know the population standard deviation. But since the standard deviation you give has 5 decimal digits after it, this is estimated from a sample, and you should use t.

Comment: The context likely is one in which an initial sample was used to obtain estimates of mean and variance.  In this case, without any additional assumptions (such as a Bayes prior), *this question cannot be answered.*  The reason is that these numbers are only *estimates.*  All we can do is use them to *estimate* the desired probability.  When doing that, it is important to assess the likely *estimation error,* which is usually offered in the form of a standard error or confidence interval.